# Am I pretty close to proving that e is irrational?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory, taylor-expansion, irrational-numbers

Show that $e=1+1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+…$ is an irrational number.

Hint: show that, for all positive integers $p$, $0<p![e−(1+1/1!+…+1/p!)]<1$. Then conclude that $e$ cannot be a ratio of two integers q/p.

Attempt #1

I am trying to utilize the hint: the base case for a proof by induction on $p$ is easy to show, but I am having some trouble carrying out the induction step.

Attempt # 2

Then I thought that instead of going for induction, perhaps use the Lagrange-remainder instead, for the function $f(x) = e^x$, evaluated at $x=1$.

Then, after expansion of $p$ terms of $e^x$, about $x=0$, and evaluated at $x=1$, I have that the hint gives
\begin{align}
p!\left[\frac {f^{(p+1)}(\xi)}{(p+1)!} (x-x_0)^{p+1}\right]
&=p!\left[\frac {e^{\xi}}{(p+1)!} (1-0)^{p+1}\right]\\
&=p!\left[\frac {e^{\xi}}{(p+1)!}\right]\\
&=\left[\frac {e^{\xi}}{(p+1)}\right]
\end{align}

for some $\xi$ $\in$ (0,1).  But now I am stuck.  Am I on the right track with using the Lagrange remainder, or should I stick with an induction proof, or perhaps try something else with the hint given?

Thanks,

Comment: You have almost proven the statement in the hint, you just need to note that $\frac{e^\zeta}{p+1} < \frac{e}{p+1} < 1$ for all $p\geq 2$ to finish it.

Comment: Hi @Kibble, ok, so I'll couple it with the base case $p=1$, and use induction, to prove the hint is satisfied.  Then I'll see what can be said from this inequality...be right back - thanks so much for your quick response.

Comment: You don't need induction here. Lagrange directly gives you $0 < p!(e- 1 - \ldots - 1/p!) < \frac{e^\zeta}{p+1} < 1$ for all $p\geq 2$. To continue take $e=q/p$ in $p!(e- 1 - \ldots - 1/p!)$ and show that this expression is then an integer. Use this in conjunction with the previous inequality to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Hi @Kibble, I was stubborn and was trying to derive the contradiction with the inequality with the lagrange form, which doesn't work.  Using the original inequality, I see now that there would be an integer between 0 and 1, which is absurd -- and the proof is done.  Can I ask you whether you think this is a concern?  The question uses the same "p" given in the inequality and in the assumption that $e$ is rational, $q/p$.  Is this a problem?  I.e., is there some loss of generality in using the same $p$, and that perhaps we have then not accounted for *all* possible integer ratios ... thanks,

Comment: Hi @Kibble, I have specifically in mind the *negative* integers ...

Comment: Or, perhaps to avoid trivialities, we can assume the ratios to be relatively prime, so that we would never consider the negative integers, as $e$ is positive? @Kibble, thanks

Comment: Yes, there is no need to consider negative integers. $e$ is positive so if it's rational it can be written as a ratio of two positive integers. Also note that the inequality you start with holds for *any* integer $p$ so it does not matter what this is. Finally note that $p!(q/p - 1 - \ldots)$ is an integer for *any* integer $q$ so there is no problem with this either.

Comment: btw feel free to answer your own question below (and you can accept it to) once you have figured out all details.

Comment: Ah right, nice and simple: since $e$ is positive and if it were rational, then it *can* be written as a ratio of positive integers - we showed this is not possible, and there isn't further consideration needed.   Thanks so much for your additional insight and comments, @Kibble.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: Try this one (It's elementary ): If $a,b,c$ are rational and $a e^2+b e +c=0$ then $a=b=c=0.$